# BMS with lead-acid battery pack

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lead-acid, bms

I assembled a lead-acid battery pack with six batteries. Is it possible to add a BMS for a lead-acid battery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

A BMS is a Battery Management (or monitoring) system. As a general rule they are a good thing.

It is used to do some combination of:

- Charge control, possibly including current limiting, sometimes all the charging process, sometimes just indicator LEDs
- Temperature monitoring, to turn off or limit discharge/charge as required when the pack gets too hot/cold
- Discharge control possibly including current limiting, possibly indicator LEDs
- State of charge monitoring and possibly display
- Balancing separate cells, this could be active or just passive, but either way it’s part of the BMS
- Communication with other systems, maybe main processor of the machine and so on

Possibly many other tasks which slip my mind at the moment.

Clearly all those I have mentioned are relevant to lead-acid batteries. Indeed, they’re relevant to any battery technology, though only rechargeable ones will worry about charge control, though they may have protection in case someone tries to charge them (or just to protect against reverse surges).

If you are asking should you make/design/get one for your system, then the answer is yes. If you want help with what it should do, we need a lot more information.

The real question is was do you want your BMS to do, and how are you making it do those things?

Comment: i have a pack of lead acide battery, i want to manage them with BMS , i was thinking that is possible except with lithium-ion technologies

Comment: Why wouldn't it work with lead-acid? I suggest designing one. Or seeing if one is avalible off the shelf. If you have more questions you'll need to start a new question. You have not told us the voltage, setup (parallel or series), expected current draw (peak, and normal), temperature range, battery technology (there are lots of different type of lead acid batteries) nor have you said what you want this BMS to do.

Comment: @HoussemOuni I think lead-acid batteries are less commonly used with BMSes because the batteries are more robust. E.g. slight overcharge is no problem (it is converted to heat) and the battery doesn't explode. Also why they don't come with balance ports - you just trickle-charge for a while and then you know all the cells are full. By contrast, trickle-charging a lipo battery will make it explode. What functions do you want the BMS to perform?

Comment: i was thinking that the utilities of the BMS is for controlling overcharge of the  battery

Comment: Not overcharging is the job of the charger. Cutting of due to overcharge from a faulty charger is the job of the BMS as a last line of safety.

Answer (score 0):

I built a gel cell charger a while ago with a UC3906 chip (see https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/power-management-pmic/battery-chargers/781?s=N4IgTCBcDaIKoGEDMBOADANhAXQL5A). Something like that may do what you want.

Comment: thank you sir, but i found that the maximum voltage supply is 40V  while i have a six pack of 12v each one, the sum of my battery pack is 72V